# SUM TOP 3 for types per user and TOP 1 for another type

Tags: sql

I have been trying to write an SQL query to select the top 3 per type per user and sum together with the top 1 of another type per user. I apologise if it sounds complex but I can't think of a better way to describe it. The query must be compatible with MySQL 5.x.

I have been trying to adapt a previous query with no joy. It has currently been setup to return the first 5 rows per type per user and treat every other row as a value of 1. I've tried to change some clauses to produce the desired effect with no joy.

```
SELECT
 wsf_ref
,sum(wsf_value) as total
from (select
*,
( select count(*)
 from individual u
 where
   t.wsf_ref = u.wsf_ref and
   t.type = u.type and
   t.wsf_value <= u.wsf_value
) as number
from individual t) t
where (number <= 3 and type <> 'blue' and status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3'))
or (number = 1 and type = 'blue' and status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3'))
group by wsf_ref
order by total desc  

Example Data
-------------------------------
id     wsf_ref   status     type       wsf_progress   wsf_value
1      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          5
2      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          10  *
3      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          20  *
4      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          10  *
5      001       Approved       blue       Day 1          10 
6      001       Approved       blue       Day 1          25  * 
7      002       Approved       red        Day 1          10
8      002       Approved       red        Day 1          20  *
9      002       Approved       red        Day 1          30  *
10     002       Approved       red        Day 1          20  *
11     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          10
12     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          20  *
13     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          15  *
14     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          40  *
15     002       Approved       blue       Day 1          20
16     002       Approved       blue       Day 1          35
17     002       Approved       blue       Day 1          50  *

* denotes rows to be summed in the example.
```

For this example the type of 'blue' is the TOP 1 only. The 'status and 'progress' are not really relevant in this example but I would like them included as WHERE criteria.

```
Expected Results
----------------------
wsf_ref     total
002         195
001         65
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `row_number()` with partitions for `wsf_ref` and `type`. Then in `where` I specified which records should be summed (top 1 for `blue` and top 3 `for other types`). If you want to fiter data by `wsf_status` you can do it in `cte`.

```
with cte as (
select
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by wsf_ref, type order by wsf_value desc) as number
from individual
--where wsf_status <your condition>
)
select
     wsf_ref
    ,sum(wsf_value) as total
from cte
where (number <= 3 and type <> 'blue')
or (number = 1 and type = 'blue')
group by wsf_ref
```

A solution without `row_number()`.

```
select
     wsf_ref
    ,sum(wsf_value) as total
from (select
  *,
  ( select count (*)
     from individual u
     where
       t.wsf_ref = u.wsf_ref and
       t.type = u.type and
       t.wsf_value <= u.wsf_value
  ) as number
from individual t) t
where (number <= 3 and type <> 'blue')
or (number = 1 and type = 'blue')
group by wsf_ref
```

With additional conditions (it's ugly, because we can't use window functions in this version of mysql)

```
select
     wsf_ref
    ,sum(wsf_value) as total
from (select
  *,
  ( select count (*)
     from (select * from individual where wsf_status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3')) u
     where
       t.wsf_ref = u.wsf_ref and
       t.type = u.type and
       t.wsf_value <= u.wsf_value
  ) as number
from (select * from individual where wsf_status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3')) t) t
where (number <= 3 and type <> 'blue')
or (number = 1 and type = 'blue')
group by wsf_ref
```

Comment: @MarkHarraway No, but it does in MySQL 8.

Comment: @shawn as i thought. It's my fault as I forgot the MySql 5.x off the question. Edited. Thanks M. Kanarkowski Thanks but I require a solution compatible with 5.x.

Comment: @MarkHarraway I added a version without row_number.

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski Sorry I can't get this to work. I've tried adding type to the first SELECT statement but that didn't help.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)
     from individual u
     where
       t.wsf_ref = u.wsf_ref and
      '

Comment: It runs without error -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/twAH7ZMHCV6CRHQ3YDCh2/1 Are you sure that you run the same select?

Comment: Got it. Your count (*) has a space. Count(*) works. Thanks

Comment: This is very strange. It works in db-fiddle but producing wrong results in my system. It's only returning the first row of each type.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, additional conditions need to be in cte/subquery (status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3')), because of this you can even filter all rows.